# Python 3 Tkinter: Grid columnspan ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My `grid` `columnspan` is ignored in the following code. The `"Ok"` button doesn't occupy full `width`.

```
class Arshi(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fontOption = tk.Toplevel()

        self.selectFont = tk.Label(self.fontOption, text="Select Font: ", font=("Courier New", 9))
        self.selectFont.grid(row=0, columnspan=1)

        self.selectedFont = tk.StringVar()
        self.fontComboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.fontOption, textvariable=self.selectedFont)
        self.fontComboBox.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1)

        self.selectFontSize = tk.Label(self.fontOption, text="Font Size: ", font=("Courier New", 9))
        self.selectFontSize.grid(row=1, columnspan=1)

        self.selectedFontSize = tk.StringVar()
        self.fontSizeComboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.fontOption, textvariable=self.selectedFontSize)
        self.fontSizeComboBox.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=1)

        self.fontProceed = tk.Button(self.fontOption, text="Ok", font=("Courier New", 9))
        self.fontProceed.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Arshi")
    root.geometry("1024x600")
    window = Arshi(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `sticky` option of the [grid geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) manager to the following line

```
self.fontProceed.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

resulting in

```
self.fontProceed.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NSEW')
```

[image]